# Java and openssl C different AES CTR encryption result

Tags: java, c, openssl, aes

I need to port application from Java to C++. I'm stuck on problem with AES CTR 128. In Java and C it has different encryption result. So my Java code.

```java
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;


class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try 
        {

            byte[] keyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode("5gYDRl00XcjqlcC5okdBSfDx46HIGZBMAvMiibVYixc=");
            byte[] ivBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==");

            SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
            String encrypted = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal("This is a plaintext message.".getBytes()));
            System.out.println(encrypted); // print: sTBJYaaGNTxCErAXbP6eXnU59Yyn1UJAp7MGQw==

        } catch (Exception e) {}
        return;
    }
}
```

My C code. I use the same algorythm, plain text, key and iv. But get another cipher text result.

```c
#include <openssl/conf.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/buffer.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *base64encode (const void *b64_encode_this, int encode_this_many_bytes)
{
    BIO *b64_bio, *mem_bio;      //Declares two OpenSSL BIOs: a base64 filter and a memory BIO.
    BUF_MEM *mem_bio_mem_ptr;    //Pointer to a "memory BIO" structure holding our base64 data.
    b64_bio = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());                      //Initialize our base64 filter BIO.
    mem_bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());                           //Initialize our memory sink BIO.
    BIO_push(b64_bio, mem_bio);            //Link the BIOs by creating a filter-sink BIO chain.
    BIO_set_flags(b64_bio, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);  //No newlines every 64 characters or less.
    BIO_write(b64_bio, b64_encode_this, encode_this_many_bytes); //Records base64 encoded data.
    BIO_flush(b64_bio);   //Flush data.  Necessary for b64 encoding, because of pad characters.
    BIO_get_mem_ptr(mem_bio, &mem_bio_mem_ptr);  //Store address of mem_bio's memory structure.
    BIO_set_close(mem_bio, BIO_NOCLOSE);   //Permit access to mem_ptr after BIOs are destroyed.
    BIO_free_all(b64_bio);  //Destroys all BIOs in chain, starting with b64 (i.e. the 1st one).
    BUF_MEM_grow(mem_bio_mem_ptr, (*mem_bio_mem_ptr).length + 1);   //Makes space for end null.
    (*mem_bio_mem_ptr).data[(*mem_bio_mem_ptr).length] = '\0';  //Adds null-terminator to tail.
    return (*mem_bio_mem_ptr).data; //Returns base-64 encoded data. (See: "buf_mem_st" struct).
}

char *base64decode (const void *b64_decode_this, int decode_this_many_bytes)
{
    BIO *b64_bio, *mem_bio;      //Declares two OpenSSL BIOs: a base64 filter and a memory BIO.
    char *base64_decoded = calloc( (decode_this_many_bytes*3)/4+1, sizeof(char) ); //+1 = null.
    b64_bio = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());                      //Initialize our base64 filter BIO.
    mem_bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());                         //Initialize our memory source BIO.
    BIO_write(mem_bio, b64_decode_this, decode_this_many_bytes); //Base64 data saved in source.
    BIO_push(b64_bio, mem_bio);          //Link the BIOs by creating a filter-source BIO chain.
    BIO_set_flags(b64_bio, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);          //Don't require trailing newlines.
    int decoded_byte_index = 0;   //Index where the next base64_decoded byte should be written.
    while ( 0 < BIO_read(b64_bio, base64_decoded+decoded_byte_index, 1) ){ //Read byte-by-byte.
        decoded_byte_index++; //Increment the index until read of BIO decoded data is complete.
    } //Once we're done reading decoded data, BIO_read returns -1 even though there's no error.
    BIO_free_all(b64_bio);  //Destroys all BIOs in chain, starting with b64 (i.e. the 1st one).
    return base64_decoded;        //Returns base-64 decoded data with trailing null terminator.
}

int encrypt(unsigned char *plaintext, int plaintext_len, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *ciphertext)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

    int len;

    int ciphertext_len;

    /* Create and initialise the context */
    ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();

    /* Initialise the encryption operation */
    EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_ctr(), NULL, key, iv);

    /* Provide the message to be encrypted, and obtain the encrypted output.
     * EVP_EncryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary
     */
    EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, plaintext, plaintext_len);
    ciphertext_len = len;

    /* Finalise the encryption. Further ciphertext bytes may be written at
     * this stage.
     */
    EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + len, &len);
    ciphertext_len += len;

    /* Clean up */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    return ciphertext_len;
}

int main (void)
{
    /* A 256 bit key */
    char keyStr[] = "5gYDRl00XcjqlcC5okdBSfDx46HIGZBMAvMiibVYixc=";
    unsigned char *key = (unsigned char *)base64decode(keyStr, strlen(keyStr));

    /* A 128 bit IV */
    char ivStr[] = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==";
    unsigned char *iv = (unsigned char *)base64decode(ivStr, strlen(ivStr));

    /* Message to be encrypted */
    unsigned char *plaintext = (unsigned char *)"This is a plaintext message.";

    /* Buffer for ciphertext */
    unsigned char ciphertext[128];
    int ciphertext_len;

    /* Initialise the library */
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    OPENSSL_config(NULL);

    /* Encrypt the plaintext */
    ciphertext_len = encrypt (plaintext, strlen ((char *)plaintext), key, iv,
                              ciphertext);

    /* Encode with Base64 */
    char *ciphertextBase64 = base64encode(ciphertext, strlen(ciphertext));
    printf("Ciphertext is: %s\n", ciphertextBase64); /* print: UL4lvWZNtDVO64ywHVkFM/uBv+lpE3DhGZrRcw== */

    /* Clean up */
    EVP_cleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

So how I can get the same result `sTBJYaaGNTxCErAXbP6eXnU59Yyn1UJAp7MGQw==` in C?

Comment: You should *not* use `AES_encrypt` and friends for OpenSSL. That's a software-only implementation, so you will not enjoy hardware support, like AES-NI. You should be using `EVP_*` functions. See [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: I rewrote C code with EVP_* functions. Anyway I got wrong ciphertext.

Comment: OpenSSL is likely adding padding. It should not matter expect for the last block, but I get the impression you have not gotten that far. Checkout [EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/EVP_EncryptInit.html). I'm guessing your immediate problem is decoding the Base64 strings. You have ntot stated anything about them, so its only speculation. Perhaps you should backup and use some hard coded keys and ivs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here AES CTR 256 not 128. Java do not explicity define bits it implicity gets from key size. So here key size has 32 bytes - 256 bits. I wrongly think that here AES CTR 128.